# Assets precompile not compiling assets for other mime_types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am having little problem when compiling assets if i specify a my application layout `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "master" %>`, the master does not get compiled when running the asset precompile command. So also i have a layout called application.mobile.erb and the assets precompile command never compiles any asset from that layout. Pls could i be doing something wrong here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify in production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w[master.js]
```

also add above all javascript files from application.mobile.erb oru use

//= require ...

in root js file, assets pipeline will know where to find them

Comment: thanks a lot for this tip. i would try. Which also means i can add what ever css and javascript i want to compile in the list

Comment: yes in same line config.assets.precompile += %w[master.js some.css another.js another.css]

Comment: tried it out but i am having this error `master.css isn't precompiled` but i have included in or am i to change it to master.css.scss

Comment: Maybe you need to add *= require_self in comment or change it to master.css.scss

Comment: i have solved the problem. i was separating the list with comas. Thank